# Best way to handle and show errors for multiple ajax requests in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

My app is a dashboard that makes several axaj requests for data on a single dashboard url.  I'm looking for best practices for handling and presenting errors to the user.  A few strategies have crossed my mind:

- Use a generic error handler in my route/controller that handles errors from every service and figures out what to do
- Create error handler methods for each service and use those to set properties on the dashboard controller

I started down this road and it got pretty messy and didn't feel very Ember-ey.  Is there a preferred way to do this?

Also, `$.ajax`'s `.fail()` method doesn't always get called because `$.ajax()` will succeed with a 200, but there's an application error in the payload.  So I have to manually check all return values for errors.

I'm looking for general guidance, not necessarily specific code.

Here's a screencap to give you an idea of what the app looks like: [screencap](http://sandalsoft.com/dashscreencap.png)

Thanks!